# Basic Blocks and Data Flow Analysis

Tags: binary-analysis, control-flow-graph

I am looking to do some Data Flow Analysis via code. I have already the code that parses a binary and disassembles it (x86/x64) and creates Basic Blocks.

Now what I would like to do is, for any Basic Block, analyze the effect of each instruction and compose all these effects to derive information
at basic block boundaries.

Also I would like to perform Variable Tracking and Live Variable Analysis. Last, CFG (Control Flow Graph) to see all these effects across basic blocks.

Is there any available C/C+ Lib or subset of any Open Source Project that can help me achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: you Can maybe reuse some piece of code from the LLVM project.

Comment: To use LLVM, first I'll need to lift my code x86 to LLVM bitcode? How do you envision the best approach to use LLVM in this case? I see the LLVM has interesting classes and functions for basic blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice framework to look at is [Triton](https://triton.quarkslab.com/) which does a good job in Dynamic Symbolic Execution. I ended up looking at the code and implementing my own solution with their same approach.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the radare project:

https://github.com/radare/radare2

Their ESIL representation of mnemonics can help you track down the access to variables, registers and even flags.

https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/disassembling/esil.html

For example, `inc edi` will result in `edi,++=,$o,of,=,$s,sf,=,$z,zf,=,$p,pf,=`